# How to revert the Draggable compoent's position when drag stops using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draggable

I have a `Draggable` component with a container in it.
I want the position of the `Draggable` to reset when the dragging is stopped (`onStop`).
This is my `Draggable`'s properties:

```
<Draggable
    axis="x"
    bounds={{top: 0, bottom: 0, left: -75, right: 0}}
    onStop={//what to do here}
>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I researched and you can just use `position={{x: 0, y: 0}}` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a position state

```
    const [pos, setPos] = useState({x:0, y:0});
```

Set the position state when the Draggable component moves using `onDrag`

```
    const [pos, setPos] = useState({x:0, y:0});
    const handleDrag = (e, data)=>{
        setPos({x:data.x, y:data.y});
    }
    <Draggable onDrag={(e, data) => handleDrag(e, data)}/>
```

Set the position back to 0 when the drag ends using `onStop`

```
    const [pos, setPos] = useState({x:0, y:0});
    const handleDrag=(e, data)=>{
        setPos({x:data.x, y:data.y});
    }
    const handleDragStop=()=>{
        setPos({x:0, y:0});
    }
    <Draggable onDrag={(e, data) => handleDrag(e, data)} 
    onStop={handleDragStop}/>
```

Set the postion of the draggable component as the state using `position`

```
    const [pos, setPos] = useState({x:0, y:0});
    const handleDrag=(e, data)=>{
        setPos({x:data.x, y:data.y});
    }
    const handleDragStop=()=>{
        setPos({x:0, y:0});
    }
    <Draggable onDrag={(e, data) => handleDrag(e, data)} 
    onStop={handleDragStop} 
    position={pos}/>
```